# inequality with exponentials!

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

Proove this inequality: 
$2(\sqrt{3}+1)^{-x}+2^x(2+\sqrt{3})^x>3$
I tried using Bernoulli, but it doesn't work. Nor does the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
take $a=(\sqrt3 +1)^x$
$\to a^2=(3+1+2\sqrt3)^{2x}=(2(2+\sqrt3))^{x}$
 $$2(\sqrt{3}+1)^{-x}+2^x(2+\sqrt{3})^x>3$$ so rewrite as
$$2a^{-1}+(a^2)>3$$and obviously $a>0$

now : note that 
$$2a^{-1}+(a^2)>3 \space \space\space\space \times a\\
2+a^3 >3a \to a^3-3a+2 >0\\ (a-1)(a^2+a-2)>0\\(a-1)(a-1)(a+2)>0\\(a-1)^2(a+2)>0  $$ to end of the proof ,we need to say $(a-1)^2 \geq 0$and $a>0 \to a+2>2>0$

Comment: Are you sure that your expression for $a^2$ is correct? It seems that you doubled the exponent *and* squared the term inside the parentheses.

Comment: @MartinR ,I'll correct it , thank you